# Sed/Awk insert spaces before lines NOT starting with pattern

Tags: sed, awk, conditional-statements, substitution

I am trying to process a log file with the following row types:

- row1 pattern1 word1 word2 pattern2
- row2 pattern1 pattern2

What I am trying to achieve is, insert pattern4 in between pat1 and pat2 for every row that doesn't include "word1 word2", i.e conditional substitution

The aim is to achieve a view like this

- row1 pattern1 pattern3 pattern2
- row2 pattern1 pattern4 pattern2

So that we can further process with awk :)

Comment: Please edit your question to show how the output should look afterwards, as it is hard to see formatting in comments.

Comment: You say you like to insert some, but do you also like to remove  `word1 word2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this works:

```
awk '!/word1 word2/  {$2=$2 " pattern4"}1' file
row1 pattern1 word1 word2 pattern2
row2 pattern1 pattern4 pattern2
```

Comment: I see I didn't ask the proper question. Edited above.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks a lot. I only had to figure out that $2=$2 should be changed to match my log file.

Thanks a lot ! :)